# Promise based counter

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am new to learning JavaScript and so have begun understanding promises.
I have written a simple code that logs the value passed to promise function as parameter, after setTimeout goes off.
If i need to create a counter using the same code, is there a way I can do that?

```
function hello(a, b) {
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(a);
        }, b);
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
    });
}
hello(5, 1500);
```

Comment: Do you mean a function that would print the first argument within the interval of your second argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the numbers of times hello's promise resolved.

Simply add a count variable and increment each time promise resolved

```js
let count = 0;
function hello(a, b) {
    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res(a);
        }, b);
    }).then((result) => {
        count++;
        console.log(`Result: ${result}, Count: ${count}`);
    });
}
hello(5, 1500);
```